# Can a Business Intelligence solution be tested?

Tags: performance

I'm developing a business intelligence solution using Microsoft BI Development Studio.  I'm Mainly using SSIS , SSAS and SSRS.

The users will be accessing the reports from a web application (ASP.NET using ReportViewer).  They are not going to be trained. The number of users at any given time is unknown but it will be limited. The reports should be available at all times.  As for the SSIS and SSAS tasks they should be executed once a month. I do not have user stories or requirements.

Is there a way to evaluate my solution's quality and performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "yes". Your application has a purpose and users, so its quality and performance can be evaluated relative to its purpose and its users.

The implied question of how to test it is one that can't be answered without more information. I'd consider these questions:

- How will users interact with the application?
- Will users be trained or not?
- How many users will be using the application at any given time?
- What expectations do users have of the application?
- What external requirements (if any) exist (e.g. is there an expectation that the application will be available at all times without exception?)?
- What level of control will there be over the server side of the application? (If you control the server hosting and users connect via a client, you don't need to specify minimum architecture for the server - or deal with users trying to run the server on underpowered systems)

That's just a starting point. I think you need to consider the requirements or user stories of your application and use those to develop your starting points for testing. If you don't have documented requirements or user stories, it might be worth your time to start there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer .
I will respond to some of your questions to provide you with some more information.
The users will be accessing the reports from a web application(ASP.NET using ReportViewer). And they are not going to be trained . 
The number of users at any given time is unknown but It will certainly be limited.
And yes the reports should be available at all times ... as for the SSIS and SSAS tasks they should be executed once a month.
I do not have user stories or requirements.

Comment: You actually have implied user stories/requirements here in the things that your users will expect and timing and scheduling of the tasks.